# How to deal with double data with two different systems (English and German) in google charts

Tags: google-visualization

I have my local system in English and my server is hosted on a German System. When I run my code for google charts it produces proper results on localhost. But when i run the code on server (German system), my numeric values gets a german notation. And thus the chart load fails. 
For example:

```
`var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Enegry', { role: 'style' } ], 
        ['2017',15782.515,'#76A7FA'],
        ['2016',0,'#76A7FA'],
        ['2015',0,'#76A7FA'],
        ['2014',0,'#76A7FA'],
        ['2013',0,'#76A7FA']]);
 `
```

This works fine since numbers have '.' as decimal separator.
Where as

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Enegry', { role: 'style' } ], 
    ['2017',15782,515,'#76A7FA'],
    ['2016',0,'#76A7FA'],
    ['2015',0,'#76A7FA'],
    ['2014',0,'#76A7FA'],
    ['2013',0,'#76A7FA']]);
```

Numeric values have ',' as separator. Thus google chart fails to load with the error message: *Row 0 has 4 columns, but must have 3*.
(The values are stored in an ArrayList)
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify a locale in the `load` statement

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'en'});
```

see [Load the Libraries -- Locales](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale)

Comment: Hello.. Thanks for your reply.. I tried this but i guess it just changes the way the values are displayed. But in background it still treats ',' as a column separator. and the code fails..

Comment: sounds like you'll either need to set the locale to `en` on the data source somehow or try to convert the number using `numeral.js`  -- otherwise google charts isn't going to handle...